# Copy and paste selected dynamic data columns from one sheet to another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I want to copy data from specific column in Sheet 1 to a specific column in Sheet 2. There are 20 such columns and that mapping is maintained in a table like

[image]

I have written the code to search column name *(source and destination sheets)* from but am unable to copy the data from source column (dynamic range) to destination column.

```
 Sub search_validate()

    Dim j As Integer

    Dim sourcSearch, destSearch As String
    Dim sCell, dCell As Range

    For j = 3 To 20

        sourcSearch = Sheet6.Range("Z" & j).Value ' pickup selected source column name 
        destSearch = Sheet6.Range("AA" & j).Value ' pickup selected destination column name 

        Set sCell = Sheet1.Rows(2).Find(What:=sourcSearch, LookIn:=xlValues, _
        LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

        Set dCell = Sheet2.Rows(2).Find(What:=destSearch, LookIn:=xlValues, _
          LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
          MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

    '  sCell.Address or sCell.Column to get source column header address but data starts after this column. dynamic range

    '  dCell.Address or dCell.Column to get destination column header address. no data in destination column except header.

    Next j

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should append the data to the end of the destination column

```
    If Not sCell Is Nothing And Not dCell Is Nothing Then
        Dim Source As Range, Target As Range
        Set Source = Intersect(Sheet1.UsedRange, sCell.EntireColumn).Offset(1)
        Set Target = Sheet2.Cells(Sheet2.Rows.Count, dCell.Column).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        Source.Copy Destination:=Target
    End If
```

Comment: This works great but only issue that is also copying the header from source which I dont want. How can we remove that?

Comment: Nevermind. Just changed this line to this and it worked flawlessly. Set Source = Intersect(Sheet1.UsedRange, sCell.EntireColumn).Offset(2)

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice that your headers start on row 2.  Thanks for accepting my answer!

Answer (score 0):

You need to paste new data after last row in your current table?
U can find last row with this:

```
lastRow = Columns("Enter your column number here").Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
```

Then just make a copy-paste, like this:

```
Set copyRange = Range(YOUR RANGE HERE)
 copyRange.Copy
Cells(lastRow + 1, "Enter your column number here").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

Comment: No. When macro is run, it will automatically clear destination sheet data. So no need to append.